# Taking a limit of $f(x,y)$ using the definition

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am reviewing for a test in my Calculus III class and I ran into a problem. I need to prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} x+y=a+b$ using the formal definition of a limit.

The definition given is:
Let $f$ be defined on the interior of a circle centered at the point $(a, b)$, except possibly
at $(a, b)$ itself. We say that $lim_{
(x,y)→(a,b)}f (x, y) = L$ if for every $ε > 0$ there exists a
$δ > 0$ such that $| f (x, y) − L| < ε$ whenever $0 <
\sqrt{(x − a)^2 + (y − b)^2} < δ$.

Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $ε > 0$ is given. Note that $0 <
\sqrt{(x − a)^2 + (y − b)^2} < δ$ implies $|x-a| < \delta$ and $|y-b|<\delta$. So if we take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then $|(x+y) - (a+b)| \leq | x-a| + |y-b| < 2\delta=\epsilon$.